# Up navigation animation

Tags: android, animation, up-navigation

So I have followed the docs about [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

However, if I want to customize what the animation transitions look like in xml, I am trying to do something like this

https://gist.github.com/lawloretienne/b8b4f68a779b9f97241f

The enter animations work well, its the exit animations that seem to not get triggered.  When the up button is clicked, it will navigate up to the logical parent activity.  However instead of the exit animations showing, the enter animations are showing.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What `launchMode` is specified for the parent activity in the manifest?

Comment: Setting android:launchMode="singleTop" on the parent activity did the trick.

Comment: That gist you link to is 404-ing, making this question pretty useless. Consider either including it or paraphrasing gists in your next question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `launchMode` must have been set to `singleInstance`. It overrides the transition animation. You should set it to `singleTop`.

Answer (score 1):

in custome_out_next.xml try this

```
<translate
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Reason of this behavior is described in [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) link:

- If the parent activity has launch mode `<singleTop>`, or the up intent contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity is brought to the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its `onNewIntent()` method.
- If the parent activity has launch mode `<standard>`, and the up intent does not contain `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity is popped off the stack, and a new instance of that activity is created on top of the stack to receive the intent.